# Using FileReader.onprogress to display progress when hashing a file (SHA256)

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, cryptography, filereader

I am using `Forge Crypto Library` to hash (SHA256) an uploaded file and output a digest. The file is being hashed fine. But if it is a large file then hashing it might take a little while. So I am trying to display a `percentage complete` field using `FileReader.onprogress`. I tried to implement it, but the progress is not being shown. It is just displaying `100`.

HTML:

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file"/>
<label id="label"></label>
```

JS:

```
$("#fileInput").change(function() {
    hashFiles(this.files);
});

function hashFiles(files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() {
            var sha256 = forge_sha256(reader.result, reader.result.length);
            alert("SHA256 is " + sha256);
        };

        reader.onerror = function() {
            alert("Could not read the file");
        };

        var currentFile = files.item(i);

        reader.onprogress = function(currentFile) {
            if (currentFile.lengthComputable) {
                var progress = parseInt(((currentFile.loaded / currentFile.total) * 100), 10);
                document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = progress;
            }
        }

        reader.readAsBinaryString(files.item(i));
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/vNQPgd?editors=101

Am I implementing `.onprogress` correctly? I don't think I need the `currentFile` variable, but I can't figure out how to correctly implement it. Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need to perform `forge_sha256(reader.result, reader.result.length);` in parts which ever method you plan to use? If `forge_sha256` is an atomic operation that doesn't report progress by itself this will never work, right?

Comment: That's what I was just realizing. This would detect the progress of `FileReader` reading the contents of the file, not the actual hashing...hmmm

Comment: You need to read the file in parts and use some kind of hash update/dofinal functionality, where update updates the inner state of the hash and dofinal performs the last calculations and returns the final state (i.e. the hash output)

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I may just revert to a loading gif

Comment: Haha, I meant just not going through the trouble of implementing a progress bar or percentage and instead displaying a loading gif or css loader

Comment: OK, but there seems to be an `md.update` defined [here](https://github.com/brillout/forge-sha256/blob/master/forge/sha256.js). So if you first get the file size, then read into a buffer and finally perform `md.update` and then `md.digest` then you *can* implement this.